# react-grid-layout order horizontally when compactType is vertical

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

Is there a way to automatically order horizontally the items in `react-grid-layout` `Responsive` layout, when the `compactType="vertical"`?

```
import { Responsive, WidthProvider } from 'react-grid-layout'

const GridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive)
...
   <GridLayout
    compactType="vertical"
    breakpoints={{ xs: 0, sm: 600, md: 1000, lg: 1300 }}
    cols={{ xs: 2, sm: 4, md: 6, xl: 8 }}
    >
      {[1, 2, 3].map((item) => (
        <div
            key={item}
            data-grid={{
                w: 2,
                h: 2,
                x: 0,   // Here I don't want to define their position
                y: 0,
                maxW: 2,
                maxH: 2,
                i: item,
            }}
        >{item}</div>
      </GridLayout>
```

Since it is a responsive grid, I would like to automatically order them horizontally, regardless the breakpoint.

Now they appear in single vertical line, but they should be horizontally ordered and if there is no place for the next item, it should start another horizontal row.

When the `compactType` is set to `vertical`, it works as expected, but it changes the behavior of the drag and drop to vertical. I want to keep the vertical behavior and change only the initial ordering.